# Custom unit vector for drawing of arc in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to label the 45° angle ACB in a triangle drawn in 3D using Ti*k*Z:

[image: Triangle]

The full circle about C has been rotated in 3D about Y, and so it is in the correct plane. However, I cannot see how to do the same for arcs: the red arc is in the xy plane. How can I rotate this arc to the correct plane?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6,z=.4cm]
    \draw[thick,dotted] (.5,0,.4) node[anchor=north]{$B$} -- (.9,0,.7) node[anchor=south west]{$A$};
    \draw[thick,dotted] (.5,0,.4) -- (.5,.5,.4) node[anchor=south]{$C$};
    \draw[thick,dotted] (.5,.5,.4) -- (.9,0,.7);
    \draw (.5,0.05,.4) -- (0.54, 0.05, 0.43) -- (0.54, 0, 0.43);

    \draw[thick] (.5,.5,.4) circle[x={(.8,0,.6)},y={(0,1,0)},radius=.2];
    \draw[thick,red] (.5,.3,.4) arc[x={(.8,0,.6)},y={(0,1,0)},start angle=-90,end angle=-45,radius=.2];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code that produces the image above instead of only the code snippet? Thank you.

Comment: @Alenanno done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also possible to define the coordinate change only for the arc, using `{[options]arc...}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6,z=.4cm]
\draw[thick,dotted] (.5,0,.4) node[anchor=north]{$B$} -- (.9,0,.7) node[anchor=south west]{$A$};
\draw[thick,dotted] (.5,0,.4) -- (.5,.5,.4) node[anchor=south]{$C$};
\draw[thick,dotted] (.5,.5,.4) -- (.9,0,.7);
\draw (.5,0.05,.4) -- (0.54, 0.05, 0.43) -- (0.54, 0, 0.43);

\draw[thick] (.5,.5,.4) circle[x={(.8,0,.6)},y={(0,1,0)},radius=.2];
\draw[thick,red] (.5,.3,.4){[x={(.8,0,.6)},y={(0,1,0)}]arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-45,radius=.2]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around, I have found that it is possible to provide the custom unit vectors to the `\draw` command rather than the `arc` command, but the point from which the arc starts must have been defined beforehand, and then referenced, otherwise the new x-vector will be used to calculate the starting coordinates:

[image: Fixed arc]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6,z=.4cm]
    \draw[thick,dotted] (.5,0,.4) node[anchor=north]{$B$} -- (.9,0,.7) node[anchor=south west]{$A$};
    \draw[thick,dotted] (.5,0,.4) -- (.5,.5,.4) node[anchor=south]{$C$};
    \draw[thick,dotted] (.5,.5,.4) -- (.9,0,.7);
    \draw (.5,0.05,.4) -- (0.54, 0.05, 0.43) -- (0.54, 0, 0.43);

    \coordinate (arcstart) at (.5,.3,.4);
    \draw[thick] (.5,.5,.4) circle[x={(.8,0,.6)},y={(0,1,0)},radius=.2];
    \draw[x={(.8,0,.6)},y={(0,1,0)},thick,red] (arcstart) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-45,radius=.2];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```